# Javascript object instead of Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm currently build my first real app in React and decided to use Redux along the way.

After implementing Redux, it seems like a difficult way to just set a component state to a plain application global javascript object? I've read that Redux does some performance stuff, but if we were to use a plain javascript object and enforcing immutable state change together with forceUpdate() whats the point of Redux? Besides cool timeline dev stuff? What am I missing? :)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you truly understood Redux, then I think that’s mission accomplished.

Redux simply adds a simple flow to managing a global JS object - global state. You can surely do it without Redux. After all it’s very small library.

So you’re not missing anything, I don’t think. Redux is just a really useful workflow that you can implement on your own. But given it’s simplicity and excellent *architecture*, it may be worth going with a proven solution.

Comment: I know the Redux library is small, but implementation wise I don't think its easy. You have to understand the flow between, actions, reducers, store configuration and component connection.

But I'm probably missing some important aspects of Redux?

Comment: You're right about the flow. But eventually the flow is there to create an understanding. Once set up its easy to share code amongst developers. Very maintainable and very dev friendly.

Comment: As I said, I don't think you missed anything. It's the simplicity that redux is all about

Comment: @MichaelFalckWedelgård Redux is much simpler than it may first appear to you, especially after you have dealt with monstrous legacy codebases where previous devs spun code in whatever manner they saw fit. Redux introduces a prescribed development path, yet is still incredibly robust. It also makes unit testing a breeze - something that isn't always possible with JS. It makes UI changes predictable, meaning code is easier to read and reason about. Take the effort to learn it, in my 15+ years as a js dev, React+Redux is by far my most enjoyable development environment.